# Maven Project Version for common modules with Continuos Delivery

Tags: java, maven-3

We have started to implement Continuos Delivery for our Java Builds using Maven and Teamcity tooling for CI and Build automation.

We have few common jars that are built as standalone jar artefacts and are consumed by web modules.

Frequency of the change to these common modules is high; we have started to adopt the approach discussed in various forums [What is the Maven way for automatic project versions when doing continuous delivery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18456111/what-is-the-maven-way-for-project-versions-when-doing-continuous-delivery) and in this blog 
http://blog.xebia.com/2012/09/30/continuous-releasing-of-maven-artifacts/ to use Major.Minor.BugFix-${revision} for all the common jars.

Value for revision is set in Parent POM as SNAPSHOT for local development and in case of Teamcity builds it is set to ${BuildNumberCounter}-${SVNRepoRevisionNumber} e.g. 1.0.0-10-233

For a Web Module that needs to consume the jar and always wants to pick the latest version Dependency range is defined as [1.0.0,2.0.0). This seems to be working fine; however to be honest we have not yet used this in anger, so will see if we hit challenges.

The problem that we have straightaway is that for local desktop development the dependency range in the Webmodule always resolves to the latest numbered release rather than snapshot build that was created by the developer for local testing of the common jar with the Web Module. We believe it is valid for the developer to be able to test the change of common jar with web modules locally. Only way it can be achieved is by committing the change and Teamcity producing new numbered release which is not ideal as it would potentially break the build of all Web Modules that use that common jar.

Wonder if anyone has faced similar problem and would have a solution.

Comment: Are those common jars modules within a multi module build or are these stand-alone projects?

Comment: These are standalone not part part of maven multi module build as these jar are used by more than one Web Modules.