# How to auto-update versions only for dependencies within multi-module/reactor build?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

When I run the following command for the `root` project, it checks for updates of ALL dependencies:

```
mvn versions:use-latest-versions
```

I want to limit versions update for only those dependencies which are reachable from the `root`:

```
root/pom.xml
├── A/pom.xml
│   └── D/pom.xml
│       └── E/pom.xml
├── B/pom.xml
└── C/pom.xml
    ├── F/pom.xml
    └── G/pom.xml
```

The group and artifact ids of these dependencies are in the current reactor build (multi-module build).

For example, I don **not** want to update external dependencies like `junit` or `commons-logging`.

There is an option **[excludeReactor](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-latest-snapshots-mojo.html#excludeReactor)**.  And I need an opposite like **includeOnlyReactor**.

Otherwise, it is unreliable and tedious work to specify all possible artifact patterns "owned" by your project via **[includes](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-latest-snapshots-mojo.html#includes)** option.

Comment: Does setting `processDependencies` to false do what you need?

Comment: @heenenee I see no difference with `-DprocessDependencies=false` or without. In fact, the description of this option doesn't make sense to me: *"Whether to process the dependencies section of the project. If not set will default to true."* How would I not want to update dependencies section if I want to use latest version of dependencies? What else can have versions to be updated by `versions` plugin except dependencies? If they mean plugins, then it's not addressing my case.

Comment: Actually **[processDependencies](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-latest-versions-mojo.html#processDependencies)** is complimentary to **[processDependencyManagement](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-latest-versions-mojo.html#processDependencyManagement)** and this is indeed not my case - I want processing all.

Comment: I added **[corresponding feature request on github](https://github.com/mojohaus/versions-maven-plugin/issues/10)**.

Answer (score 0):

Set module dependencies version to `${project.version}`  Good practice is to do it in dependencyMnaagement section of root pom.

Example:

```
<project>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
<artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>


<modules>
    <module>A</module>
    <module>B</module>
    <module>C</module>
</modules


<dependencyManagement>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>A</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>B</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    ...And so on....

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>G</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>


</project>
```

Then whenever you want to use the module in another module (e.g. module G in B) you put just

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>B</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

To change version of the project use `mvn versions:set`. This will keep all the modules in the same version and the dependency management section will keep the dependencies in the same version as well.

Obviously it won't work if you want to keep your modules in same version all the time. But this will be more tricky anyway.

Comment: The [`versions:set` page](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/set-mojo.html) says *Sets the current project's version and based on that change propagates that change **onto any child modules** as necessary.* However, the question is not related to child-parent relationship of Maven artifacts (when they use tag `<parent>` to inherit configuration). Instead, it is related to *selection of Maven artifacts to be affected* through sub-modules (using `<module>` tag in the "parent" `pom.xml`) in reactor build.

Comment: The expected result is that artifacts being built as part of the reactor build get updated versions for those `groupId:artifactId` dependencies which are part of the same reactor build.

Comment: I've added the example. The trick is that you don't add versions to the dependencies that are part of the reactor build at all. You lock them at `${project.version}` so that the dependency version is always the same as the whole project version.

Comment: OK. I see... In my case, the dependencies are completely independent projects with their own release lifecycle and, therefore, different latest versions `X.Y.Z`, `N.M.P`, `I.J.K`, ... and/or `-SNAPSHOT` variants (yes, they may still be within the same reactor build simply for the sake of convenience to rebuilt using single root `pom.xml`). The most frequent use case - move/migrate/update dependencies of all current-reactor-built projects to latest versions of current-reactor-built dependencies (because, normally, its better to use latest versions).

Comment: Ideally, update should be automatic (e.g. by `mvn versions:use-latest-versions` after fixing its logic and using some flags to limit update of versions for current-reactor-built dependencies.). And then (before testing, fixing, and committing changes) there is a possible need to revert just a few `pom.xml` files for components which were decided to be moved/migrated/updated to the latest of their dependencies somewhere later.

Comment: I understand. Then keeping this in single Maven reactor project will be a pain. You could potentially keep the versions in the `dependencyManagement` section of root and just update manually. However this will cause problems if project `A` uses `1.0.0` version of parent, and project `B` uses `1.0.1` version of parent (the `parent` has version and `relativePath` not knowing why). And what if project A wants to use E v. 2.0.5 and project B wants to use E v. 2.0.7? Also note that to use `mvn versions:use-latest-versions` you first need to `install` artifacts in repo.

Comment: _"And what if project A wants to use E v. 2.0.5 and project B wants to use E v. 2.0.7?"_ Yes, it is a pain, but the idea is that, in general, all projects keep moving to the latest. So, the pain is within exceptions (changes in which corresponding `pom.xml` files will have to be reverted after running the `mvn versions:set ...`) - the majority (hopefully all) will still stay on the latest known versions. See also **[my latest clarifications](https://github.com/mojohaus/versions-maven-plugin/issues/10#issuecomment-279229191)** for GitHub feature request.